# Mongo Db How to detect error in pipeline?

Tags: mongodb

I need to join two collection with two conditions.

```
products:
{
  ...
  sku: "4234",
  organizationId: ObjectId("asdasdasd);
  ...
};

order_history:
{
  ...
  itemSku: "4234",
  organizationId: ObjectId("asdasdasd);
  ...
}
```

I chose pipeline approach:

```
$lookup: {
  from: 'order_history',
  let: { foreign_sku: "$itemSku", foreign_organizationId: "$organizationId" },
  pipeline: [
    {
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $and: [
            { $eq: ["$organizationId", "$$foreign_organizationId"] },
            { $eq: ["$sku", "$$foreign_sku" ] }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  as: 'order_history'
}
```

I wrote it on base of Mongo Documentation, but my conditions are ignored.
I have scalar multiplication in result. Where is my mistake?

Comment: You need to join `order_history` with `products`. So you have added `from:'order_history'` in lookup. But `let` variables should be from `product` collection, not from order history collection. Your `$itemSku` and `$organizationId` are coming from `order_history` colelction

Answer (score 2):

I already mention in the comment and the code is below

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "order_history",
      let: {
        foreign_sku: "$sku",
        foreign_organizationId: "$organizationId"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$organizationId",
                    "$$foreign_organizationId"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$itemSku",
                    "$$foreign_sku"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "order_history"
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AKg_I00ujxw)**